# Why is my shallow well pump cycling on and off after tanks were emptied?

Tags: water, well-pump, pressure

We have a Gould JRS5 shallow well jet pump. Our water tanks were emptied for cleaning. Now that we have refilled them and turned the water pump back on, it cycles on and off continually.

Water pressure is consistent and good in the house, however even when water is not running in the house it cycles on, pressurizes up to 60, turns off, the pressure drops to 40 right away, and then the pump turns back on.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the tank is water logged, no air in the tank to pressurize the tank.

Did you leave a tap/faucet open to let out the air when filling the tank the first time?

If so drain the tank about half way, make sure all taps are closed and then turn on the pump.

This is assuming you do not have air bladders in the tank.